# Literature on the merge-tree algorithm?

Tags: fluid-framework

There is a "merge-tree" algorithm for the collab of sequence-like DDSes, but the documentation is weak. Is there any formal literature on the details?

Comment: There's no documentation on this at the moment, but it's on our list to add!